# Twitter OAuth library for Facebook Connect functionality for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, authentication, facebook, modal-dialog, twitter-oauth

I'm looking for a library that allows me to authenticate via Twitter's OAuth schema that looks and works similar to Facebook Connect for iPhone. Searching on here and Google I found some examples but they are a  year or two old and none of them were complete. Some had a modal pop up others had a OAuth library but I haven't found one that does everything like the Facebook Connect library. I could work to get the different examples working together but I just feel like this has already been done by a great number of different apps and there would be an easy tutorial or demo out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this:

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

This uses the infamous MGTwitterEngine and adds in OAuth support to it. This is a very powerful library and works quite nicely.